# Will my APP get approved if it does not has data persistence? and I keep the model in the appDelegate

Tags: ios, app-store

Good day, everyone, I'm new to iOS development, programming in general actually, quick question, will my APP get approved if it does not has data persistence?

It's a quick and small text manipulation kind of APP, it reads the data, process it, then done with it (send out the results via email), I just don't see the needs of doing persistence, and also, the model is basically being put in the appDelegate, for each tabBarController to work with. Everything works just the way I expected, not sure if that's (no data persistence + use appDelegate to keep shared model) really and could get my APP rejected?

Thanks for your time answering my questions :)

Comment: you don't have do use data persistency.

Comment: Does your app claim to preserve data?  I would think that it is import your app behaves as described would be factor in being approved or not.

Comment: nope, I'm all good then, thank you Júlio and Mike :)

Comment: On the other hand, if the user switches your app to the background, iOS kills it, the user switches back, they might be annoyed if their work is lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer: No. Your app will not get rejected.

Apps that's get rejected are usually violating something serious, like consuming to much CPU, calling Apples private APIs, responding to user input in an unpredictable manner or simply crashing etc - not just code design issues.

It sounds however like you should consider moving your model some place else, for the sake of ease the maintenance of your code.

Consider creating a modelClass that implements the [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern. The purpose and responsibility of the AppDelegate should be limited to starting up your app and controlling its lifecycle

Comment: Thanks EsbenB, that's a relief to hear, thank you so much. I'm fairly new to programming, to me, the appDelegate is actually kinda nice place to put things which I wanna other view controller to be able to access, it's a centralised location (=easy to maintain) as well, is that a bad habit?

Comment: My pleasure, Tylr. I fully understand your need to share data between various VC .Please see my updated answer

Comment: Thanks again EsbenB, Singleton, got it, I'll surely do some digging and refactor my code later